# CRC check corrupted BZ2

Tags: python

Is there a way to check the CRC validity of a BZ2 file in python?

I'm using it to check a PNG in a corrupted BZ2 file

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking for a corrupted file, assume it is intact:

```
import bz2

try:
  bz2.BZ2File(zipFile).read()
  print 'Intact'
except IOError:
  print 'Corrupted'
```

Comment: I even did:

    try:
      print bz2.decompress(data)
    except IOError:
      pass
But I need a faster way, that's why I asked for CRC check

I know

    binascii.crc32(data)

But how to check it's validity?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350355/handling-single-file-extraction-from-corrupted-gz-tar

Comment: I found this [gzip.py](http://coverage.livinglogic.de/Lib/gzip.py.html) python file, but I don't understand how `_read_eof()` checked the validity of CRC32